# Need java class comment to appear in following format(Automatically)

Tags: java, javadoc

I am using Eclipse for development, and want class comment to appear in following format(Automatically) . I tried  modifying Templates from Preference but it didn't help. Please advice.

```
 /*+----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ||
    ||  Class abc.xyz.TestClass
    ||
    ||         @author:  ABC
    ||
    ||        Purpose:  XXXXXX
    ||
    ||        implements: com.abc.I1, com.abc.I2
    ||        extends: com.abc.xyz.C1
    ||                  
    |+-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Comment: As a note, if this is for real-world code, you should try as hard as practical to use Javadoc. It's the official standard, and it's supported by a large variety of tools (such as IDE tooltips).

Comment: I gotta agree with chrylis; this is the reason for JavaDocs. Have you ever hovered over a method call, and saw the details for it in a little popup window? This is a JavaDoc tooltip. Just add one more `*` at the beginning of your comment: `/**`. As for this, Im pretty sure you need to adjust trailing whitespace and indenting in your Formatting options

Comment: Not to mention the manually edited mentioning of implicit class information like class name, implements and extends. This will melt on the first refactoring performed by a tool.

Answer (score 0):

Try Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates and check automatically add comments.